# Routing for a Static Exported Next JS site on S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, routes, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

I'm using Next JS to export a static HTML site that is uploaded on S3 and hosted on Cloudfront. I don't want to upload it onto a node server and just want it fully static. I don't know if I'm doing something incorrectly or missing out on something but the hosted site on cloudfront does not seem to have any routes. Hence, although I can access the site on the main page ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)), if I try to reach a relative path ([www.mysite.com/page1](http://www.mysite.com/page1)), I can't reach it unless I do ([www.mysite.com/page1.html](http://www.mysite.com/page1.html)). That's when I realized that Cloudfront just points to the S3 bucket and does not have any way to generate routes. Is there a good way to provide Cloudfront with those routes?

I've looked online for solutions and tried the below:
-Implemented exportPathMaps: I might have done this incorrectly. An example would help if you have one
-turned on trailingSlash
-used Lambda edge to reroute the user to [www.mysite.com/page1.html](http://www.mysite.com/page1.html) while preserving the URL to [www.mysite.com/page1](http://www.mysite.com/page1). <- This method is too costly as it used lambda so I don't like it

For now, I have a redirect script that does what the lambda edge function does (append the .HTML onto the request) but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The simplest (IMO best) way is to use lambda to redirect the traffic.  I'm not sure what you mean by costly, but - price-wise, it's inexpensive (free for most sites), and there is almost no latency.  I've been using this method for nearly two years without issues.  It's not clear in your question, but the lambda function should resolve the correct `HTML` file but not append `.html` in the browser's address. The address should show as `example.com/page` - without `.html.` - if you need help resolving the correct route without appending .html, let me know.

Comment: You can also rewrite URLs using CloudFront Functions, which are faster and less expensive than Lambda@Edge in the majority of cases. In addition to including 1TB of outgoing data transfer for free each month, the CloudFront Free Tier also includes 2MM monthly invocations of CloudFront Functions. Depending on your traffic levels, that means you can likely implement this at no cost. Example of a rewrite here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda trigger to copy any new file in the s3 bucket which has a  key like `key/index.html` as `key` or `key/`.
This is what I use :

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
        CopySource: "/" + event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name + "/" + event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
        Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/index.html$/g, '')
    };
    s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
    });
    
    var params2 = {
        Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
        CopySource: "/" + event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name + "/" + event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
        Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\/index.html$/g, '')
    };
    s3.copyObject(params2, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
    });
    
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What we found is nextjs router pathname is not populated with the expected route on first hit if you use next export. Until this issue is fixed within nextjs, you can use a provider in _app.js that wraps your components and adjusts the route or put this before the return statement inside you _app.js default function:

```html
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const { asPath, push, pathname } = useRouter()
if (asPath.split('?')[0] != pathname.split('?')[0] && !pathname.includes('[')) {
    // Work around for next export breaking SPA routing on first hit
    console.log('Browser route ' + asPath + ' did not match nextjs router route ' + pathname)
    push(asPath)
    return <div>Loading...</div>
}
```